# How to get max value from sql table with group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table

```
Id | Version | DateFrom   | DateTo     |
_______________________________________
1  | 1       | 2015-09-15 | 2015-09-18 |
1  | 2       | 2015-09-15 | 2015-09-18 |
1  | 3       | 2015-09-15 | 2015-09-20 | --different date
1  | 4       | 2015-09-15 | 2015-09-18 |
2  | 1       | 2015-09-15 | 2015-09-18 |
2  | 2       | 2015-09-15 | 2015-09-18 |
```

And I'm trying to make a view which return records with the lastest version independently from the rest of the columns.
So for example I expect:

```
Id | Version | DateFrom   | DateTo     |
_______________________________________
1  | 4       | 2015-09-15 | 2015-09-18 |
2  | 2       | 2015-09-15 | 2015-09-18 |
```

This is what I already did:

```
Select
    Id,
    MAX([Version]) AS Version,
    DateFrom,
    DateTo  
FROM
    dbo.Table_1
Group By
    Id,
    DateFrom,
    DateTo
```

But the result is:

```
Id | Version | DateFrom   | DateTo     |
_______________________________________
1  | 4       | 2015-09-15 | 2015-09-18 |
1  | 3       | 2015-09-15 | 2015-09-20 |
2  | 2       | 2015-09-15 | 2015-09-18 |
```

Comment: why not just `GROUP BY Id`?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov, that GROUP BY is invalid. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions.

Comment: @jarlh and even if it will (there is an option to allow it) , grouping by `ID` won't work.

Comment: @jarlh, [why](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5b917/2/0)?

Comment: This looks a bit like m$sql/sql-server

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov, the general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: @jarlh, did you follow my link to SQL fiddle? `GROUP BY Id` actually works on MySQL 5.6 there. Do you mean [`ONLY FULL GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) in 5.7?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov, no I didn't. Why write code that isn't forward compatible? (Nor correct.)

Comment: My bad, it's MS SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can also be done with a left join :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM YourTable t
LEFT JOIN YourTable s
 ON(t.id = s.id AND t.version < s.version)
WHERE s.version is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a sub-query that returns each id's max version. Join with that result:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join (select id, max(version) as maxversion
      from tablename
      group by id) t2
    on t1.id = t2.id and t1.version = t2.maxversion
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run that kind of query :

```
Select ID, version, dateFrom, dateTo
from table_1 a
where not exists (
 select 1 
 from table_1 b 
 where a.id = b.id and a.version < b.version)
```